# decrease progress bar on radio input value click

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, progress-bar

I have 2 separate code in one audit.php file and trying to combine it to decrease progress bar by the value of click on radio input I just can't put the logic together The calculation should be (var total/$auditno * 100/100)

Variable

```
$auditno = "20";
```

Function for decrease progress bar, this is where calculation (var total/$auditno * 100/100) should replace value=v1-10

```
function decrease() {
var v1=document.getElementById('p1').value;
document.getElementById("p1").value= v1 - 10;
}
```

Function to calculate value of click radio input

```
function setRadios() {
        function sumRadios() {  
        var total = 0, i = 1, oForm = this.form;
        while (radgrp = oForm.elements['Set' + (i++)])
        {
            j = radgrp.length;
            do
                if (radgrp[--j].checked)
                {
                    total += Number(radgrp[j].value);
                    break;
                }
            while (j);
        }
                oForm.elements.total.value = total.toFixed(2);
    }
var i = 0, input, inputs = document.getElementById('myemailform').getElementsByTagName('input');
while (input = inputs.item(i++))
    if (input.name.match(/^Set\d+$/))
        input.onclick = sumRadios;
}

onload = setRadios;
```

and Html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<form id="myemailform">
<fieldset class="audit">
<legend>Set 1</legend>
<input id="r1" type="radio" name="Set1" value="0" /><label for="r1">0</label><br />
<input id="r2" type="radio" name="Set1" value="1" /><label for="r2">1</label><br />
<input id="r3" type="radio" name="Set1" value="2" /><label for="r3">2</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="audit">
<legend>Set 2</legend>
<input id="r4" type="radio" name="Set2" value="0" /><label for="r4">0</label><br />
<input id="r5" type="radio" name="Set2" value="1" /><label for="r5">1</label><br />
<input id="r6" type="radio" name="Set2" value="2" /><label for="r6">2</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="audit">
<legend>Set 3</legend>
<input id="r7" type="radio" name="Set3" value="0" /><label for="r7">0</label><br />
<input id="r8" type="radio" name="Set3" value="1" /><label for="r8">1</label><br />
<input id="r9" type="radio" name="Set3" value="2" /><label for="r9">2</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="position:relative;top:36px;width:140px;">
<input id="total" type="text" name="total" value="" /><strong> total</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="reset" style="font-size:11px;" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div><br><br>

<progress value="100" max="100" id=p1>100%</progress>
<input type=button value='Decrease' onClick='decrease();'>
```

Comment: where is you php code ? use tags wisely

Comment: My Php code holds the variable $auditno which is in same file above html code